# Finding out file names from inside FileReader

Tags: java, filenames, filereader

For an assignment I'm coding, we have to include print statements that tell us what file is being worked on. However, all that is passed in the methods that is in anyway related to the file is the FileReader.

The file names are taken from string args in the main method, this method then creates the file reader and passes it to the methods. Rules of the assignment mean we are **not able to edit the main methods, or our method headers.**

So my question is is there a way to backtrack through a file reader to get a string name?

**EDIT**: Talked to the lecturer, he said to; 'use the string arguments', the ones that are only passed to the readers and writers.

**EDIT2**: Lecturer messed up, ended up allowing us to edit the main methods.

Comment: It would be interesting to check a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of the code that you can't change.

Comment: *"not able to edit the main methods, or our method headers."* I don't understand the term 'method header'.  DYM that you are not able to change the method **signature** of the `main(String[])` method?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: http://jsfiddle.net/KmGHF/

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes essentially. Header being the 'private void exampleMethod (String code) {' portion.

Comment: Someone else might come up with a solution, if you are only given the FileReader, this is basically impossible. The FileReader doesn't store the name of the file it operates on. Backtracking wouldn't work because the name of a file is not stored next to its data, but rather in a file system data structure somewhere completely different.

Comment: `private void exampleMethod (String code) {`  Post actual method names, not made up nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write another class with it's own static void main(String[]).  The method would capture and print the arguments then call the original main() method.  Technically that doesn't violate the rules.

Comment: I suppose that does come under 'help method'. Cheers.